# How to detect when another application is launched in Android

Tags: android

I need to develop an application which prevents other applications from starting. Use case looks like this.

1. User starts the application.
2. System prevents application from starting and displays a dialog with reason explanation instead.

I found this application which does the similar job, but for a different use case: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree

Do you have an idea on how the problem can be solved?

Comment: What is the application? Is this something you wish to push to the Play Store?

Comment: This is not supported, as it is counter to the design intent of Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their installation instructions, it sounds like the app you linked uses the [device administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to immediately lock the screen when certain apps are started.  This probably relies on a common hack for detecting which other apps are running.  That hack has been broken in Android 5.

The only way to actually stop other apps from launching is to use the new [screen pinning API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) in Android 5.  This only works when your app is in the foreground, and only if it has been granted the screen pinning permission by the [device owner app](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20device%20owner).  On a non-rooted device, the device owner can only be set during the initial setup after a factory reset.  Otherwise, the user will be asked to allow the lock every time you try it.